# Should I add an preposition before "the day before yesterday"?

Tags: prepositions

Should it be

> "**The** day before yesterday we went to a supermarket and (we?) bought beef and chicken"

Or it should be

> "**In** **the** day before yesterday we went to a supermarket and (we?) bought beef and chicken"?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the original sentence; you do not need a preposition:

> The day before yesterday, we went to a supermarket and bought beef and chicken.

(I did add a comma after *yesterday*.)

---

However, if you *want* to add a preposition, you can do so. But it should be **on** rather than **in**:

> On the day before yesterday, we went to a supermarket and bought beef and chicken.

Note that even though it's grammatical, this sounds slightly odd to me. (It may sound fine to others.)